# Force the call to the specialized method

Tags: java

We've had an interesting corner case today at work, regarding method calling in Java. Imagine the following:

```
class Bar {}

class ExtendedBar extends Bar {}

class Foo {
   void doFoo(Bar bar) {}
}

class ExtendedFoo extends Foo {
   void doFoo(ExtendedBar exBar) {}
}
```

Now you have an instance of `ExtendedBar` and you want to call `doFoo()` on an instance of `ExtendedFoo`. In our tests the runtime picked `Foo`s `doFoo(Bar)` implementation, not `doFoo(ExtendedBar)` from `ExtendedFoo`.

Of course there is an easy way around this issue - we simply needed to rename `doFoo` to something else - but still, it struck us if it would be somehow possible without renaming the method, to keep the method's name as it is used in a strong conventional context here.

Comment: Hint: `doFoo(ExtendedBar)` *does **not*** `Override` `doFoo(Bar)`. The *name* isn't really the problem, the methods have different signatures.

Comment: If "_you have an instance of ExtendedBar and you want to call doFoo() on an instance of ExtendedFoo_" then it should pick `doFoo(ExtendedBar)`. See this : http://ideone.com/sJCZ3W

Comment: @Hackerdarshi Huh, you're right, then I guess I had a different problem (running under Android ART here, not native JVM). Thanks for clearing that up (and ideone is bookmarked :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it straightly, since you're not *overriding* the method but *shading* it. You can assert that very easily by adding a `@Override` on it. Note that if you did this with the return type it would work fine :

```
class Foo {
    Bar doFoo() { return null; }
}

class ExtendedFoo extends Foo {
    @Override
    ExtendedBar doFoo() { return null; }
}
```

but as long as you change the parameters, **it's a different signature**.

What you can do in that case is using genericity I guess.

```
class Foo<BAR extends Bar> {
    void doFoo(BAR bar) {}
}

class ExtendedFoo extends Foo<ExtendedBar> {
    @Override
    void doFoo(ExtendedBar exBar) {}
}
```

Now because you are actually and properly *overriding* the method, the JRE will resolve the method call properly and call the specialized one.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the things that were said by others: why you try here ... is simply wrong.

Defining an inheritance-hierarchy requires more thought than just putting "extends Something" on your classes. You want to make sure that you understand the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

In your case: a sub class should **never** *restrict* any of the parameter types of methods defined in some base class. You can *restrict* the return types (for example returning Long when base class returns Number); but for "input" parameters, you can only widen (allow Number, when base class uses Long).

The idea of proper OO modeling means: in any piece of source code that is using a `Foo` object ... you should be able to replace that `Foo` object with an `ExtendedFoo` object. And your proposal breaks that rule.

Comment: Absolutely understood - and I would personally not come up with such an idea myself, if I wouldn't have been forced to do something ugly like this in the context of a DI library I'm using (Dagger2).